# How to avoid circular references in record structures declaration

Tags: delphi, record, circular-reference

I would like to implement 2 record structures with imlicit type casts:

```
  TMyRecord1=record
    X, Y: Integer;
    //other fields specific to TMyRecord1
    class operator Implicit(const Rec: TMyRecord2): TMyRecord1; //<- problem: TMyRecord2 undeclared
  end;

  TMyRecord2=record
    X, Y: Real;
    //other fields specific to TMyRecord2
    class operator Implicit(const Rec: TMyRecord1): TMyRecord2;
  end;

  class operator TMyRecord1.Implicit(const Rec: TMyRecord2): TMyRecord1;
  begin
    Result.X:=Round(Rec.X);
    Result.Y:=Round(Rec.Y);
  end;

  class operator TMyRecord2.Implicit(const Rec: TMyRecord1): TMyRecord2;
  begin
    Result.X:=Rec.X;
    Result.Y:=Rec.Y;
  end;
```

The problem is the circular reference.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Helpers do not support operator overloading, otherwise that could have been a resolution to the circular reference.

Comment: This one of those problems that Emba don't seem prepared to deal with. It's a real headache.

Comment: tldr : have `TMyRecord2` implement both casts.